# how to order wordpress search by meta key values?

Tags: wordpress, meta-key

During search in 2 meta key( say acf hr_archive_title and acf hr_archive_question ), I want to list down post in following order.

1. first preference is post with searched text found in hr_archive_title
2. then posts with searched text found in hr_archive_question

example data1: hr_archive_title - HR-fråga 1432 - Rekryteringsbonus; hr_archive_question - lorem ipsum

example data2: hr_archive_title - HR-fråga 1223 - Rekryteringskonsult i Norge - Rekryteringsbonus; hr_archive_question - Har det påverkat er rekryteringsprocess på något vis?

example data3: hr_archive_title - HR-fråga 1167 - Linkedin Recruiter; hr_archive_question - Har det påverkat er rekryteringsprocess på något vis?

Now when I search for 'Rekrytering' the listing should be as data1, data2, data3. Is this possible? Itried the following but to no avail. The listing is coming as mixed list.

[Display results of one meta key and order by a different meta key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151372/display-results-of-one-meta-key-and-order-by-a-different-meta-key)

https://www.billerickson.net/wp-query-sort-by-meta/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218709/order-by-custom-field-value

Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'title_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'hr_archive_title',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'question_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'hr_archive_question',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title_clause'
) );
```

This will pull posts that have **both** meta keys set, but sort them by the `hr_archive_title` meta. `meta_query` is an array of meta clauses, each clause is an associative array with an identifier key. Then you set the `orderby` parameter to listen to the `title_clause` meta clause.

This exact query might not get you what you want, but play with the idea of "clauses" for your `meta_query` and you should be able to achieve what you are trying to do.

Idea taken from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246358/70417

Comment: this is not what I want exactly. I want to search the word in either title OR question ( not in BOTH title and question ).So meta_query relation will be 'OR' in my case.
Let's say when I search for specific word, the listing comes as follows.
title1
title2
quetion1
title3
title4
But I like the listing as
title1
title2
title3
title4
question1
How can I achieve this ?